# How can I type a Grave Accent (`) on the iPad’s Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I’ve been using my iPad more and more (especially here on Ask Different) and I’ve found that I can’t find the grave accent character (also known as the "backtick" or "opening single quote"); it's the un-shifted <kbd>-</kbd> key on the standard US keyboard.

Where can I find this character on the iOS keyboard?

Comment: Just FYI - the dupe is not really a dupe because getting to the key is very different if you are using an iPad or an iPhone.  This answer worked for me, but the dupe didn't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using the virtual keyboard, tap the  <kbd>.?123</kbd>, the press and hold <kbd>**‘**</kbd> (apostrophe).  The key will expand out, just select <kbd>**`**</kbd> (grave accent).  It will be last character in the list that pops up.

Comment: alternatively, just hold the letter you want the grave accent over [assuming you don't just want a solo backtick] & you get a similar list.

Comment: No need to press `.?123`, you can just hold the `.'` key and you'll see the option.

Comment: I’m on a US keyboard as indicated in the question

Answer (score -3):

1. Download Gboard
2. Switch to 123
3. Hold apostrophe '
4. Choose first one (grave accent)

[image: example]

Comment: Why is it necessary to delete all other keyboards? How does one type a grave accent with Gboard once installed? Please [edit] your answer to fully answer the question